# How do I make sure the UI updates to the correct image on click?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I am working on a UWP project with xaml and c#. I have a stackpanel of images on the right where you can click on the image and it will display a related larger image to the left of the stackpanel.

The large image is set initially to the "large" image that relates to the first "small" image in the stackpanel when you load the page but when you click any of the other small images in the stackpanel, the large image does not update.

The whole thing is a datatemplate that is placed inside a flyout. The relevant xaml for the "large" image is here:

```
<Border Background="White" Grid.Row="2">
    <Image Stretch="Uniform">
        <Image.Source>
            <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding SelectedImage}" />
        </Image.Source>
    </Image>
</Border>
```

When the small image is clicked, it triggers the "tapped" method for that image and that method is:

```
private void Image_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var img = ((Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image)sender).DataContext as obj
    img.FlyoutContent.SelectedImage = new Uri(img.relatedPath);
}
```

I am using the above code to set the image initially and it works. It just does not change the large image when the small one is clicked.

In debugging, when I click on the small image in the stackpanel, I break at the "image tapped" method and I can see that the uri is getting updated properly and there are no binding errors. The UI never changes.

What am I missing?

Thank you,
Zach

*Side note: the "obj" is just a made up name of a custom class.

Comment: It looks a bit like you are settings the source for the clicked Image, which probably already shows the image. Are you sure that you are changing the imagesource of the correct Image?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. Are you asking if I am simply reassigning the same uri to the large image?

Comment: I am asking whether it is the correct DataContext object that you are obtaining the reference to. Is the SelectedImage path different from what you are changing it to, before you change it?

Comment: Yes the path is different.

Comment: A quick Question, Why StackPanel to load list of Images? Why Not ListView? is this a design requirement? Reason why i am asking you this is because, when you use ListView, you can bind the selected item data context to your larger image, that way eliminate lot of tapping events.

Comment: @AVKNaidu I honestly don't know. I am new to windows universal apps and xaml. I did not know ListView would be a better way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `Binding` properties you need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`class so that the UI gets updated automatically.

```
class CustomClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string _imageLink;
    public string ImageLink
    {
        get
        {
            return _imageLink;
        }
        set
        {
            _imageLink = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }

}
```

Or as you are using a `Tapped` event, why not give your XAML element a `x:name` and set the source of the image of that name to your `URi`.

To update the `ImageLink` property, you need to create an instance of the `CustomClass` in the page you are changing the property.

`CustomClass ab = new CustomClass();`

`ab.ImageLink = "code here";`

Comment: I will try the INotifyPropertyChanged. I cannot use "x:name" because it is in a datatemplate that is called as a flyout. I tried it but it will not even find the name in the code behind.

Comment: Yeah I have worked with `datatemplates` and this is true for them. So in that case INotifyPropertyChanged is your way to go.

Comment: [CallerMemberName] is the name of the function which will initiate the change. But it handles the procedure itself, you do not need to worry about it.

Comment: @zachboy82 Please mark the answer as accepted if it helps to solve your problem, so in future it can help others. Thanks